# Java SlotMachine class

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I am writing a slot machine class that generates 3 arrays of 3 random numbers and checks if all of the numbers match, if so they are declared a winner. I have written another program to run 1000 slot machines and count the winners.  The problem I am facing is that it always gives me 0 winners.  Any help?  Here is the code for each:

the SlotMachine class

```
import java.util.*;

public class SlotMachine{

    private int[] row1 = new int[3];
    private int[] row2 = new int[3];
    private int[] row3 = new int[3];

    public SlotMachine() {
        playMachine();
    }

    public void playMachine() {

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
            row1[counter] = rand.nextInt(10);
        }

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
            row2[counter] = rand.nextInt(10);
        }

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
            row3[counter] = rand.nextInt(10);
        }
    }

    public boolean isWinner() {

        if (row1[0] == row1[1]) {
            if (row1[0] == row1[2]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (row2[0] == row2[1]) {
            if (row2[0] == row2[2]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (row3[0] == row3[1]) {
            if (row3[0] == row3[2]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
     }
}
```

The win counter:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Play1000SlotMachines {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SlotMachine slotMachine = new SlotMachine();
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (slotMachine.isWinner() == true) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("From 1000 slot machines, " + count + " were winners.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never re-roll the slot machine. I also changed the name of the method, to reflect this implementation. If you would rather play 1000 different slot machines, move the declaration of a new slot machine into the for loop. This will create 1000 different instances of the slot machine class, rather than the below implementation where a single instance of a slot machine is created which is then played 1000 times. An important distinction.

```
public class PlaySlotMachine1000Times {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SlotMachine slotMachine = new SlotMachine();
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      slotMachine.playMachine();
      if (slotMachine.isWinner())
         count++;
    }
    System.out.println("From 1000 slot machines, " + count + " were winners.");
  }
}
```

Comment: You also can omit the `== true` in the `if` condition and write `count++;` in the `if`-body.